# Demand (it) of someone to infinitive

Tags: grammar

> 1. I demanded of him to take me.
> 2. I demanded it of him to take me.

Do I need "it" as referring to "to take me" ?
or is it grammatically incorrect to insert "it"?

I think both would be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither sounds right. These are some sentences that you could say instead:

> I demanded that he take me.
>
> I commanded him to take me.
>
> I demanded it of him.

You would only use *it* to substitute for *his taking me*. It is redundant and incorrect to include both *it* and what *it* refers to.

As for *demand* - I think *demand that he* is the way one usually expresses making a demand of someone, rather than *demand of him* - unless you are talking about some *thing* (i.e. noun phrase, like *it*) rather than an action (i.e. verb phrase, like *to take me*). In other words - “demand [something] of him” but “demand that he [do something].”

I don’t think “I demanded him to take me” sounds natural, but *command* has a similar meaning to *demand* and can be used in its place here.